# Where can I find a full proof of the Chern-Gauss-Bonnet theorem ?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology

Hello, 
I am looking for a proof for the Chern-Gauss-Bonnet theorem. All I have found so far that I find satisfactory is a proof that the euler class defined via Chern-Weil theory is equal to the pullback of the Thom class by the zero section, but I would like a proof of the fact that this class gives the Euler characteristic when coupled to the fundamental class. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's in the last volume of Spivak's book, no?

Comment: What's wrong with Chern's paper?

Comment: Quote from Chern: "It helps to be vague with bundles." 

Comment: Check out Bryant's answer to this question:
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/84521/a-question-on-generalized-gauss-bonnet-theorem

Comment: @Agol: yes, that's probably the best reference...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For a complete proof of the Gauss-Bonnet-Chern for *arbitrary* vector bundles (not just tangent bundles) see Section 8.3.2  of  [these notes](http://www.nd.edu/~lnicolae/Lectures.pdf). The proof is Chern's original proof,  based on Chern-Weil theory, but the language is more modern.

For a purely topological proof, see  Section 5.3 of   [these  notes](http://www.nd.edu/~lnicolae/MS.pdf).

Comment: I fixed the broken links above.

Comment: Thanks! Looks perfect, although the proof in the first ref is basically the same as what I had previously seen, though my reference had a simpler approach, examining the case of 2-plane bundles and using the splitting principle to finish. 

Answer (score 3):

One reference that seems fairly good and that I just found by googling those key words is https://web.archive.org/web/20100524152105/http://www.math.upenn.edu/~alina/GaussBonnetFormula.pdf.

The first time I learnt this, however, was with these lecture notes:
F. Mercuri, P. Piccione, D. V. Tausk, *Notes on Morse theory*, Publicações Matemáticas do IMPA, Rio de Janeiro, 2001, ISBN 85-244-0178-8; which maybe a little hard to find, but are very nicely written and I like them very much. Though, the proof you are looking for should be widely available elsewhere (google gives thousands of results, and I only looked at the first ones)...

Answer (score 0):

Chern's original paper may be found at:  Chern, Shiing-Shen (1945), "On the curvatura integra in Riemannian manifold", Annals of Mathematics 46 (4): 674–684; this citing quoted from the Wikipedia entry, though I have a copy of the
original paper somewhere in the piles in my office.